# PHP Daemon - Receive commands from Browser?

Tags: php, redis, message-queue, zeromq

I like to write a PHP script which will run in the background on Linux.

I am trying to figure out what are the solution to send and receive the meta data between PHP Daemon (script) and browsers clients?

I thought I could include http request handling in the daemon itself but a daemon script could receive 500-1000 requests every second. So http request in the daemon itself wouldn't be a good solution.

Is Redis or ZeroMQ are solution to this? Something like this:

```
(browser clients) <-----> redis <-----> PHP Daemon Script
```

If PHP Daemon send a message to a client then browser should get meta data immediately via ajax (long polling).

Comment: The best solution, hands down, is using [Mongrel2](http://mongrel2.org). It's a web server that uses ZeroMQ as its transport layer. HTTP or WebSocket protocol is represented the same and it delivers the messages to a ZMQ endpoint - this is where your script kicks in. You can either have one daemon on one machine, or million daemons that process requests in a round-robin fashion. Or you can implement entire HTTP parsing yourself / use websockets (where you have to implement websocket parsing yourself + connection handling towards the browser). Mongrel2 outperforms any server available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chris Brand gave you the answer, websockets.  I just want to go into a little more detail about your question to help point out some misconceptions that you've got.

The only effective way to make a non-http connection out of the browser is with [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) - it's the only interface that the browser has to communicate to an external server without including the full http overhead.

Your diagram:

```
(browser clients) <-----> redis <-----> PHP Daemon Script
```

... seems to treat redis as a communication protocol, which it's not, it's a data store.  You wouldn't be passing communication from the browser to a PHP script using redis any more than you would use MySQL for the same task.  Regardless, upon first glance it appears as though Redis is not capable of receiving a websocket connection directly, so you can't connect the browser directly to it in any event, so the picture would look more like:

```
(browser clients) <-----> PHP Daemon Script <-----> redis (or any other data store)
```

You *can* use ZMQ to manage your communication if you wish, and there may be compelling reasons to do so but that's application specific.  Regardless, ZMQ would live *on top of* websockets, and add its own brand of overhead to do so.  That said, it's designed for just this sort of high volume messaging.

My suggestion is to look into using websockets directly to communicate to your backend.  Chris Brand made another good suggestion to look into using node.js, but the learning curve (while relatively small if you're familiar with JS) may not be worth it for this iteration of your project.  If you run into issues of messaging/connection reliability, then you might look into what ZMQ can offer you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Jason I understood clearly now. Yea I was considering using  node.js for my project, hopefully the learning curve is not too deep. I do have some JS experience. If I do decided to go with node.js then that diagram would still work? like this:  `(browser clients websocket) <-----> node.js <-----> redis or ZMQ`

Comment: I want to reiterate that redis and ZMQ do *not* serve the same purpose. redis is a data store, ZMQ is a messaging framework. I'm guessing that the confusion is coming from the fact that redis does have some limited messaging/pub-sub capability. To answer your question, yes, the same diagram holds for node or PHP.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the browser to get feedback in realtime via long polling...I don't think Redis is an option. As far as I know, Redis doesn't allow for long poll queries...if the value doesn't exist at the time of query...it will return null.

My suggestion would be to use something like websockets. PHP has a few libraries that work with websockets, one I am familiar with is http://socketo.me/. However, this will mean that the client will interact directly with your PHP script. You can scale this by adding a load balancer infront of it and having multiple daemons on different ports/boxes etc.

If you don't have to use PHP, I would rather suggest something like NodeJS. It's made to do things like this and it does by default what things like Ratchet PHP tries to mimick.

Comment: I think Redis will work with ajax long polling. Correct if I am wrong.. Basically PHP Daemon script will use redis for storing the values and ajax long polling will check the response from Redis...

Comment: I suppose it's possible if you poll via another PHP script (not sure how if a direct connection from the front end would work anyway) and then have the script keep the connection open until Redis responds. You can probably then use a session identifier to have a unique key per user session/connection.